# Spring Exception Handling using @ControllerAdvice

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, api, exception

I have created an **APIExceptionHandler** class to handle custom **Runtime Exceptions**.
One of the **Exception** classes that I have created is **PasswordMismatchException**. So whenever an exception is encountered I return a response of type **APIResponse**.

Now my question is why the expected **Response** is not getting generated when using **CompletableFuture**.

**APIResponse.java**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class APIResponse {
    private Map<String, String> response;
}
```

**Exception Handler (CompletableFuture)**

```
    @ExceptionHandler(PasswordMismatchException.class)
    public CompletionStage<ResponseEntity<APIResponse>> passwordMismatchExceptionHandler(PasswordMismatchException exception) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Collections.singletonMap(MESSAGE_FIELD, exception.getMessage()))
                .thenApply(APIResponse::new)
                .thenApply(response -> new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
    }
```

**Response (not as expected)**

```
{
    "done": true,
    "cancelled": false,
    "completedExceptionally": false,
    "numberOfDependents": 0
}
```

**Exception Handler (normal)**

```
    @ExceptionHandler(PasswordMismatchException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<APIResponse> passwordMismatchExceptionHandler(PasswordMismatchException exception) {
        Map<String, String> errorMessageMap = Collections.singletonMap(MESSAGE_FIELD, exception.getMessage());
        APIResponse response = new APIResponse(errorMessageMap);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

**Response (as expected)**

```
{
    "response": {
        "message": "Password did not match with Repeated Password."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In spring boot the `ObjectMapper` by default used the `getters` and `setters` for [Serialization and Deserialization](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java), while the response type is `CompletionStage` the object mapper will be serializing corresponding child object (for example [CompletableFuture](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java)) and serializing method starts with `get` and `is`

```
public boolean isDone()
public boolean isCancelled()
public boolean isCompletedExceptionally()
public int getNumberOfDependents()
```

And since then name of method is `get` which returns the final object, the `objectmapper` is simply ignoring it

```
public T get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
```

Comment: Ok then how is it any different from sending a response from a controller? For eg the following controller sends a serialized response. 
`@PostMapping("/register")
    public CompletionStage<ResponseEntity<UserResponse>> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody RegisterUserRequest registerUserRequest) {
        log.info("Received request to register User: " + registerUserRequest.toString());
        return userService.registerUser(registerUserRequest)
                .thenApply(ResponseEntity::ok);
    }`